# Office 365 ProPlus - calendar entry for manager for my appts

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

At work we are using Office 365 ProPlus Version 1902 under Win 10.  For myself, I create calendar appointments for my personal appointments.  My manager wants me to send my appointments to her where, once she accepts them, they appear on her calendar but *don't affect her status* ("Free / Working Elsewhere / Tentative / Busy / Out-of-office") for the time period of the appointment.  Currently, I send them as Meetings where recipients are "Optional Attendees" and status is set to "Free".  Unfortunately that causes my calendar to show me as "free" (which I'm obviously not).  She doesn't have time to be bothered with having to check the calendars of all her direct-reports.  A group calendar might work but there is some "resistance" to this solution.

How can I send some type of Office 365 calendar item that:

- Shows me as "Busy", "Out-of-Office" or "Working Elsewhere"
- That I can send to other individuals or a group distro list
- Doesn't affect the availability status of recipients who "Accept" the invitation
- Appears on the recipient(s) calendar as related to me
- [optionally] Doesn't remind the recipients.
- That I can cancel
- That disappears from the calendar of the recipient(s) when I cancel the appt.

I have some knowledge of Office VBA so I might be able to try & code something, but want to make sure this capability isn't built into Office 365.

(note: Migrated from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566973/office-365-proplus-calendar-entry-for-manager-for-my-appts))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Office 365, why not set up an Office 365 group? On the Group Calendar invite yourself, it will go on your schedule. Don't invite your manager but show them the group calendar in Outlook and how they can overlay them. IF there are others that book on that Group Calendar, she would see their appointments as well. If you are OOO you could note that and even categorize various types of events by color.  This post might be helpful. - https://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/what-are-office-365-group

Comment: As noted, there is not much interest in Group calendars.  For one thing, they consume way too much screen real-estate because they show all the individual team members.  BTW, the link you provided doesn't work for me.